# How to version Visual Studio artifacts?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

When I build a Maven project, the artifact version is in the `pom.xml` file. In Gradle, it's in the `gradle.properties` or `build.gradle` file. In NodeJS, it's in the `package.json` file.

Is there an equivalent approach when versioning Visual Studio solution (`*.sln`) artifacts, so when I publish the artifact it will use that version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio, MsBuild and Nuget support lockfiles. You need to enable them to generate them though. Almost the whole world chose an opt-out system, the .NET ecosystem has an opt-in one. Support was added with Visual Studio 2017 if I remember correctly.

Edit your project files and add:

```
<Project>     
   <PropertyGroup>         
      <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>     
   </PropertyGroup> 
</Project>
```

To enforce a restore in locked mode, add:

```
<RestoreLockedMode>true</RestoreLockedMode>
```

And optionally make that conditional to do that autmatically on CI:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
        <RestoreLockedMode 
            Condition="'$(RestoreLockedMode)' == '' 
                and ('$(TF_BUILD)' != '' 
                or '$(CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION)' != '')"
        >
          true
        </RestoreLockedMode>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You can also pass these properties in from the command line with either dotnet or msbuild:

```
> dotnet restore --locked-mode
> msbuild /t:restore /p:RestoreLockedMode=true
```

These properties are set for each .NET project file. It's not a solution wide property.

See also:

- https://jessehouwing.net/99-percent-of-code-isnt-yours/